# Can't set value for TimeofDay, it's always null

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a class named `employee` with a propertie `aStart` of type TimeofDay.
When I try to set the value of `startWork` of an instance of employee it doesn't work. It's always null.
Funnily enough it works with all the other properties of employee. (types: String, DateTime, int) #
Below the code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Employee {
  TimeOfDay start;

  TimeOfDay get getStart => this.start = start;

  set setStart(TimeOfDay start) => this.start = start;

  Employee(this.start);
}


import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:testProjekt/employee.dart';

class FirstPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FirstPageState createState() => _FirstPageState();

  Employee employee;

  FirstPage(this.employee);
}

class _FirstPageState extends State<FirstPage> {
  TimeOfDay _time = TimeOfDay.now();

  _selectTime(BuildContext context) async {
    final TimeOfDay picked = await showTimePicker(
        context: context,
        initialTime: _time,
        builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
          return MediaQuery(
            data: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith(alwaysUse24HourFormat: true),
            child: child,
          );
        });
    if (picked != null)
      setState(() {
        _time = picked;
      });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Column(
      children: [
        SizedBox(
          height: 50,
        ),
        Container(
          child: ElevatedButton(
            child: Text('selectTime'),
            onPressed: () => _selectTime(context),
          ),
        ),
        Text('selected Time:' + '$_time'),
        Container(
          child: ElevatedButton(
              child: Text('saveTime'),
              onPressed: () => {
                    widget.employee.setStart = _time,
                    print(widget.employee.getStart.toString())
                  }),
        ),
        Text('SaveTimeofEmployee:'),
      ],
    ));
  }
}


import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:testProjekt/employee.dart';
import 'package:testProjekt/firstPage.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  Employee employee;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(home: FirstPage(employee));
  }
}
```

Comment: Please, provide a runnable example to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Please indent properly. It makes it much easier for everyone (including you) to read your code.

Comment: You are assigning something to `setAStart`, that doesn't seem to be a real setter.

Comment: @Thierry   I've just provide a runnable example.

Comment: @kuhnroyal you are right, in my simplified example I've just edited Vscode throws the exception: The setter 'setStart=' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: setStart=Instance of 'TimeOfDay'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there are a couple of things wrong with your example.

1. Lots of typos, missing semicolons and wrong lambda syntax `() => {}`. This may be caused by copying and adapting. So next time use some IDE/Dartpad/Codepen before you copy code so you can make sure it at least compiles.
2. You never construct an employee. `MyApp.employee` is `null` and is never assigned. This results in the `FirstPage.employee` also being `null` and thus causing your error.
3. Your setter/getter naming is not great. Read more here: https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#getters-and-setters

I have corrected all the typos/errors and created a codepen that works. But it is not possible to exactly say what is wrong based on your sample code.
https://codepen.io/kuhnroyal/pen/YzpYZPR